# .apk file rename .man

Tags: android, android-studio

I have develop an application with android studio and generate sign apk and I put on web but if I download apk file on device rename it to .apk to .man and after I rename .man to .apk application could not installed.
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Where did you put it online? How did you download it to your device and what device are you using?

Can you install the app through Android Studio and run it successfully?

Comment: On some website. I download from chrome on device. Yes I can install from android studio and run successfully.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to install it? Do you have installation from Unknown Sources enabled in the security settings?

Comment: On package installer show error app not installed. Yes unknown source is enable.

Comment: Can you describe in detail the steps you take? I understand from your question that you have the APK hosted on a site (can you add a link to it here?) and that when you download it with chrome on your device it is renamed with the .man extension. You rename it to .apk and try to install it?

Comment: Yes, excuse I can't put in link here.

Comment: I upload it on drop box public and test it's OK and download with apk format but again show error until installation process app not installed.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your error to the question.

Comment: You can see error on question

Comment: There are a number of reasons that could happen. Can you post the output of logcat when you are trying to install it?

Comment: Yes but few hours later I can check logcat.

Comment: In logcat signature do not match the previously installed version

Answer (score 2):

It's a apache side problem.
You should add a type for APK like below:

open httpd.conf and add below config.

`AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk`

restart your apache demon!

Answer (score 1):

It is work awesome tries it follow.

file director (folder)

Example: public_html/file

In this root Create .htaccess

And upload in .htaccess following codes.

```html
# Don't Edit this file unless you know what are you doing.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^data/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ index.php?dir=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^data/file/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ file.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^data/down/([0-9]+)/(.*).html$ down.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^updates/([0-9]+).html$ more_updates.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^feed$ rss.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>


# blocheaza accesul la fisierul htaccess

<Files .htaccess>

order allow,deny

deny from all

</Files>

AddType application/octet-stream .csv
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .avi
AddType application/octet-stream .mpg
AddType application/octet-stream .mov
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
AddType application/octet-stream .jpg
AddType application/octet-stream .jpeg
AddType application/octet-stream .gif
AddType application/octet-stream .3gp
AddType application/octet-stream .mp4
AddType application/octet-stream .txt
AddType application/octet-stream .jar
AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk

# blocheaza executarea anumitor fisiere

RemoveType .pl .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .xml .phtml .phtm .html .htm .wml .shtm .shtml .asp

RemoveHandler .pl .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .xml .phtml .phtm .html .htm .wml .shtm .shtml .asp

#php_flag engine off

Options -Indexes
```

Here See one thing

AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk

Now your problem has been solved from man to apk

If you need further assistance leaves a comment here, I will be right back.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a previous version of the app signed with the debug key still installed. Please completely uninstall it and try reinstalling your desired, downloaded apk. You can uninstall it from the commandline with:

```
$ adb uninstall com.some.app
```

If that does not work then it is possible that your downloaded APK is not signed at all, though that prints out a different error message. You can check the signature on an APK with:

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs some_app.apk
```

If you see "CN=Android Debug", this means the .apk was signed with the debug key generated by the Android SDK
(means it is unsigned), else u will find something for CN.
for more details
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html